# Find this 2 groups?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $X$ be a group such that $Y\trianglelefteq X$. Find group $X, Y $ such that $Y\trianglelefteq X$ and $Y$ has a subgroup $Z\leq Y$ such that $Z\trianglelefteq X$.

Comment: You could take $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ all to be equal to the trivial group that contains only the identity element.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that a trivial chain of abelian groups suits your question. Take $\langle 4\rangle \leq \langle 2 \rangle \leq \mathbb{Z}$. Since all these groups are abelian, any subgroup is a normal group.

Comment: is X = <2> or is it Y = <2>?

Comment: If you want $Z \leq Y \leq X$ then it is $Y=\langle 2 \rangle$

Comment: And what would than X be if I want to be more specific?

Comment: That should be $\mathbb{Z}$